# How to find the vector equation of a plane that makes an angle with an xy-plane?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

How do you find the vector equation of a plane $P=Ax+By+Cz+D$ that makes an angle of $6^{\circ}$ with the $xy$-plane ($z=0$) and has the origin and the position vector $(-3,~9, -1)$ on its plane?

My solution so far: Let $n_1$ be the normal vector of $z=0$ and $n_2$ be the normal vector of $P$.
I tried to use the equation: $$\cos\theta = \frac{n_1.n_2}{|n_1||n_2|},$$ 
I end up getting: $$\cos(6) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}},$$

and I also used the the equation: $$(r-a).n_2=0$$

to get:$$-3A+9B-C=0$$

Now I don't know where to go from here. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you are doing fine. First hint to continue: since the plane contains the origin, what must the value of D be? Second hint: the vector (A,B,C) can be multiplied by any escalar; or, equivalently, you can choose its module at will.